# How to convert extracted .csv file from SFMC Data Extension to FTP location with UTF 8 Encoding?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, soap-api, sfmc-business-unit, data-extract

I am successful in extracting data into .csv from data extension to ftp location using Data Extension Extract API. The **issue I am facing here is extracted .csv file is having some other Encoding type and I need only UTF-8 encoding**. Just a quick note is I am not using any GUI, I am **using SOAP API for Data Extension Data Extract**. Can anybody please help me with this issue ?

Data Extension Data Extract : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.htm

Comment: Not actually.. I want some parameter in my soap api request which will change the default encoding to UTF-8 while uploading file to FTP

Comment: That ain't going to happen. The files are encoded to UCS-2... simples. Follow EazyE's pointer (there are a bunch of other SE answers on this subject), or get with living with UCS-2 encoded files.